# What is the files property of input tag with file type?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display the content of uploaded text file , and it works. But I don't know why there is a `files[0]` property of `textfile`. I try to search the internet but there is no result about this.

```
<center>
    <input id="textfile" type="file">
    <input id="upload" type="submit" value="Upload">
</center>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var textfile = document.getElementById("textfile");
    var upload = document.getElementById("upload");

    upload.addEventListener("click",function () {
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.readAsText(textfile.files[0]);
        fileReader.onload = function (event) {
            alert(event.target.result);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: According to mozilla developer site,
_File objects are generally retrieved from a FileList object returned as a result of a user selecting files using the <input> element_
So even though not multiple, File API fetches an array itself with one element.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `files` property contains  the list of files that were selected in the `<input type="file">` element. It's a list because you can use the `multiple` attribute to allow the user to select multiple files; without this option, the only selected file will always be in `files[0]`. It's a [`FileList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList), which is array-like so you can access elements with ordinary array indexing syntax. Using the same representation for both single and multiple file selectors keeps things consistent in the code that processes the input -- you don't have to worry about whether there's a single `.file` property or a `.files` property with a list.

Each element is a [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object that contains information about the selected file(s). And you can pass this to the `FileReader` API to access the file contents.

Answer (score 1):

According to mozilla developer site,

> File objects are generally retrieved from a FileList object returned
>   as a result of a user selecting files using the  element.

So even though not multiple, File API fetches an array itself with one element.